# sms window will not close after sending or cancelling sms

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

```
- (IBAction)SendTxt:(id)sender {

MFMessageComposeViewController *textComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

[textComposer setMessageComposeDelegate:self];

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    [textComposer setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123456",@"123456", nil]];
    [textComposer setBody:@"HELP ME"];
    [self presentViewController:textComposer animated:YES completion:NO];


}

    else {
        NSLog(@"Can't open Text");
    }
}




-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result


{

switch (result) {
    case MessageComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"SENT");
        break;

    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"FAILED");
        break;

    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

}
```

I have the above code which brings up the sms window as normal..
It works ok and sends a SMS but the SMS window will not close after sending or cancelling..
The NSLog registers the send or cancel but the SMS window will not go away!

Can anyone help?
Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dismiss it yourself using

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ // something to do on completion if you need}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but where would I put this? Also i jsut want it to dismiss the window and be on the page it was before! (i am a noob)

Comment: switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"SENT");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"FAILED");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
            
All works great now!!